# how to access a function in a promise

Tags: es6-promise

my code in react application

I have I class:

```
class SampleModuleController{

    getSampleModuleSheet()
    {
       console.log("getSampleModuleSheet");
       return tableSheet;
    }
    retrivePageData(pageNumber,pageLength){
        
        console.log("retrivePageData calledd");
        let pageData= asyncAwaitService.findTablePageTestData(pageNumber,pageLength);
        return pageData;
    }
}

export let sampleModuleController = new SampleModuleController();
```

SampleModuleController class lazy loaded and its getSampleModuleSheet method can use successfully.

in jsx:

```
<DataTable getPageData={import('../controllers/sampleModuleContrller').then(({sampleModuleController}) => {return sampleModuleController.retrivePageData;})} />
```

in js file:

```
async newPageManager(){
    console.debug("this.props.getPageData------",this.props.getPageData);
    let pageData = await props.getPageData(1,34);
}
```

out put

[image]

so how can I call the fuction inside the promise

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? How is your function called?

Comment: So what is `this.props.getPageData`. What made you think it was a function? Can you provide the definition of this property?

Comment: because in out put (log) it shows as a function with "f"

Comment: based on output, I would think it was either `(await this.props.getPageData).retrievePageData(1, 34)` or `(await this.props.getPageData)(1, 34)`, since it is indicating the promise, when resolved, will return a named function.  did you try either of these approaches?

Comment: also, I'm not sure you need to await this, since it is already resolved in this scope

Comment: @Brett Caswell i will try

Comment: I haven't worked much with async await pattern in javascript, so I can't say with much certainty.  if `retrievePageData` in this promise is equivalent to `.Result` of a task in c#.. then perhaps `var r = await this.props.getPageData;` is all that is necessary here. in which case, the `pageNumber` and `pageLength` are hints, and are probably separate properties on `props` type

Comment: @Brett Caswell i used your second  solution and it works.im trying here to create component that cosumer can give function as a property to load what ever data he want .so dont know the function name.so i used your second solution.plese add it as a answer

Comment: I can do that, it's actually a bit more apparent with your question update as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your jsx, it's apparent that the promise returns a method delegate.

So, `this.props.getPageData` when resolved with `await` will result in a method delegate that is itself to be invoked on.

we'll modify your snippet as followed;

```
async newPageManager(){
    console.debug("this.props.getPageData------",this.props.getPageData);
    let getPageData = await props.getPageData; 
    let pageData = getPageData(1,34);
}
```

---

additionally, since `props.getPageData` is returning a promise, it is *thenable*.

so, you could pass the result of that promise into a `then` function scope -- something like the following

```
async newPageManager(){
    console.debug("this.props.getPageData------",this.props.getPageData);
    let getFirstPagePromise = props.getPageData.then((fn) => fn.bind(this, 1, 32)); 
    let getFirstPage = await getFirstPagePromise;
    let pageData = getFirstPage();
}
```